# Error on the mean for discrete histogram

Tags: discrete-data, uncertainty, discrete-distributions

Suppose I have a discrete histogram, in this case the number of votes for each rating (1-5 stars) for a product.
I can calculate the sample mean easily enough, and get an average score for this product.

But  how do I calculate the error on the mean?

Comment: Perhaps it is a stretch to consider data for 1 to 5 stars as numerical (instead of ordinal categorical). If you do take data to be numerical: in my answer you have $K=5$ 'histogram' bins each with only one unique number of stars with appropriate frequency $f_j.$ So the 'approximations' for $\bar X$ and $S_X$ are exact. With a large number of observations, it is hard to imagine that $\bar X$ is far from $\mu.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have $K$ histogram bins, each centered at midpoint $m_j$ and
containing frequencies $f_j$ of data values, for $j = 1,2,\dots,K,$ then you can approximate
the sample mean as
$$\bar X \approx \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j = 1}^K f_jm_j,$$
where $n = \sum_{j=1}^K f_j.$ And you can approximate the sample
variance as
$$S_X^2 \approx \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{j=1}^K f_j(m_j - \bar X)^2.$$
Then $V(\bar X) = \sigma_{\bar X}^2 = \sigma_X^2/n,$ where $\sigma_X^2$
is the population variance. Also, $SD(\bar X) = \sigma/\sqrt{n},$
often called the 'standard error of the mean, can be estimated
as $S_X^2/\sqrt{n}.$

Furthermore, if your data are nearly normal, an approximate 95% confidence interval for
the population mean $\mu_X$ is of the form
$$\bar X\pm t^*\frac{S_X}{\sqrt{n}},$$
where $t^*$ cuts probability $0.025 = 2.5\%$ from $\mathsf{T}(\nu=n-1),$
Student's t distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom.

*Example:* Consider the sample $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ of size $n=100$
from the distribution $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 50, \sigma=5),$ sampled in
R below, summarized, and shown in a labeled frequency histogram.

```
set.seed(2020)
x = rnorm(100, 50, 5)
summary(x);  sd(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  34.81   47.19   50.60   50.54   53.70   66.01 
[1] 5.596459
```

A 95% confidence from, the procedure `t.test` in R,
is $(49.43, 51,65).$

```
t.test(x)$conf.int
[1] 49.43400 51.65492
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95
```

The following R code makes the histogram. The tick marks along the
horizontal axis, made by `rug(x)` show the exact positions of the
100 data points. (Typically, you will not have this information; we
do not use it below.)

The approximations discussed above and illustrated below assume that all data points in a histogram
bin are located at the bin midpoint. Typically, this method of approximation
gives useful results as long as the histogram has a sufficient number
of intervals.

```
cutp = seq(33,69, by=4)
hist(x, br=cutp, ylim=c(0,40), label=T, col="skyblue2")
rug(x)
```

[image]

The sample mean `a` 50.56 below from the histogram
estimates $\bar X = 50.54$ from the original data above,
and the sample SD `s` 5.77 from the histogram estimates
$S_X = 5.60$ from above.

```
m = seq(35, 67, by= 4)
f =  c(2, 3, 9, 22, 34, 19, 7, 3, 1)
n = sum(f);  a = sum(f*m)/n;  n;  a
[1] 100
[1] 50.56
v = sum(f*(m-a)^2)/(n-1);  s = sqrt(v);  v;  s
[1] 33.25899
[1] 5.767061
```

A 95% CI based on the sample mean and SD approximated from the histogram
is $(49.42, 51.70)$.

Of course this is not exactly the 95% CI $(49.43, 51,65)$ that one would
have gotten from the original data, but it is close enough for most
practical purposes.

```
q = qt(.975, 99);  q
[1] 1.984217
pm = c(-1,1);  a + pm*q*s/10
[1] 49.41569 51.70431
```